# Visual Studio 2019のC#にて参照0の関数、変数を警告に出したいのですが、可能でしょうか？

Tags: c#, visual-studio

privateな関数、変数は可能なのですが、public関数や、変数も出したいと思っています。

Comment: 可能性としては[ソース コード分析の概要](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview)の中の コード品質ルールの構成オプション/コード分析ルールの構成ファイル/不要なコード規則 あたりで何とか設定するか、自分でそうした何かを作成して [サードパーティ製アナライザーのインストール](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/code-quality/install-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019) で対処するとか？

Comment: ちなみにヘルプ記事 [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を参考に、検出されるもの/されないものの両方の例(他の人が検証可能なソースコード全体)を提示して、検出されないもののうちどれが検出されて欲しいか等を追記した方が、助言や回答が付きやすいでしょう。

Comment: こんなページがあるようなので、サードパーティ製ツールを試してみてはどうでしょう？ 全体：[Code Inspections in C#](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Code_Inspections_CSHARP.html), 一例：[Code Inspection: Type is never used (non-private accessibility)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/UnusedType.Global.html)